# Django: How to return a Model query expression from a function?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
jobQuery = getJobQuery()
job = jobType.objects().get(jobQuery)
```

How do I implement `getJobQuery()` to return an expression equivalent to:

```
jobType.objects().get(in_progress=False)
```

Comment: How does the result in the second tie into the first?

Comment: YOu can do this by pk:  `job = jobType.objects.get(pk=jobQuery.pk)`

Comment: Essentially I want to capture the query expression into an expression that could be returned from a function.

Comment: Doing some more research, it seems that a Q object is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Q object is 100% what you're looking for.

```
def get_job_query():
    return Q(in_progress=False)
```

alternatively, though, rely on the fact that querysets are lazy.

```
def get_job_query():
    return JobType.objects.filter(in_progress=False)
job = get_job_query().get()
```

for extra style points, you can attach that to a custom Manager for JobType.